# the program comes to log1 then it stops.what is wrong?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        TextView txtno=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtno);
        TextView txtyes=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtyes);
        Log.i("log1","s");
        txtno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"no",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("log2","s");
            }
        });

        txtyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"yes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("log3","s");
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: provide your logcat

Comment: You have `setContentView(layout)` twice in activity. Have one and then on some action like button click you can show a dialog. Quick search on stackoverflow or google should help you. Comment out `setContentView(R.layout.dialog);`

Comment: the error occurs after log1 and it"s : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Custom dialog you need to set

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
```

Comment: Thanks.you're Perfect

Answer (score 0):

Please remove  setContentView(R.layout.dialog); this line. You must have only one layout in your activity Oncreate. If yo want dialog, use alert dialog on some button OnclickListener. Or use Splash Screen To have your dialog in it.